# Como pasar de instrucción sql a entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Tengo este query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'A' THEN Auth_Area  END) A,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'B' THEN Auth_Area END) B,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'C' THEN Auth_Area END) C
FROM tbAutorizacion  
WHERE Id = 'Valor busqueda' 
AND Area IN ('A','B','C')
```

y no he encontrado como pasarlo ya que no cuenta la misma estructura en Entity Framework.

Comment: Conviertelo en una vista y llama la vista. Si necesitas parámetros, conviertelo en un procedimiento almacenado y llama el procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: Tienes algún ejemplo de como poder realizarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las consultas orientadas a objetos se hacen utilizando **Linq**:

```
var lista = tbAutorizacion.Where(t => t.id == "Valor Busqueda").AsQueryable();
var A = lista.Max(l => l.Area == "A");
var B = lista.Max(l => l.Area == "B");
var C = lista.Max(l => l.Area == "C");
```

Primero haces una consulta **Linq** que filtre por el id especificado y posteriormente haces una consulta individual para obtener el máximo de las áreas que te interesan, estos máximos serán guardados en las **variables A**, **B**, **C**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: ¿Esa opción lee la tabla una sola vez o tiene que leerla 3 veces?

Comment: una vez, q es la primera consulta, para optimizarla en vez de ToList, al final puedo poner AsQueryable() y asi la consulta se ejecuta del lado del servidor(suponiendo q la base de datos este aparte en un servidor) y ya se cargaria con el filtro hecho en la pc cliente, el resto de las consultas ya son sobre la lista

Comment: Y ahí como retornaría los datos buscados?, ya que sql me retorna los valores asi 
valorA  | valorB  | valorC
NO       |   SI     |    SI

Comment: @EnriquedeJesusJuarezCruz donde vas a mostrar los datos?

Comment: Pienso hacerlo en un array para poder evaluar y actualizar una tabla, pero mi duda aqui es, que si una vez asi teniendo los datos, como que en las 3 campos obtenga campo A = SI, CampoB = SI, CampoC = SI, como actualizarlo seria el problema

Comment: @EnriquedeJesusJuarezCruz resolviste?